# Connecting to different schema while executing oracle scripts via Ant

Tags: oracle, ant

Basically the ant sql task does the following:

1. Deletes all the tables present in SchemaA
2. Creates then the table for SchemaA
3. Deletes all the tables present in SchemaB
4. Creates then the table for SchemaB

   ```
   <target name="exexcuteORACLE">
   <sql driver="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:1521:orcl" userid="username" password="pass" print="yes">
       <classpath>
           <pathelement location="${src.driversdir}/oracle/ojdbc6.jar" />
       </classpath>
       <transaction src="${src.sqldir}/oracle/drop_tablesSchemaA.sql" />
       <transaction src="${src.sqldir}/oracle/create_tablesSchemaA.sql" />
       <transaction src="${src.sqldir}/oracle/drop_tablesSchemaB.sql" />           
       <transaction src="${src.sqldir}/oracle/create_tablesSchemaB.sql" />
       <transaction src="${src.sqldir}/oracle/count_table_script.sql" />
   </sql>
   ```

The Problem is that "create_tablesSchemaB.sql" doesn't create tables for SchemaB but it creates for SchemaA only. So basically SchemaA has all the tables.
Is there a script which says to connect to SchemaA or "Connect SchemaA"?

Comment: Is there are reason you can't split it into two `<sql>` blocks with different credentials?

Comment: I did that already and its working fine. But like in mysql I just said Use 'SchemaA' and Use 'SchemaB' and it worked. Do we have something similar.?

Comment: From within the `create_tablesSchemaB.sql` script, say? It depends what privs you have as the user you connect as. You can change your current schema, or prepend the table names with the schema you want to create them in, but only if you have enough privs (create any table). You might be able to just connect from within the script if you embed the credentials, but that doesn't seem ideal, and i'm not sure if that works through JDBC.

Answer (score 0):

This is because most likely your call is not changing context for 2nd schema

Possible solutions could be...

1. if you have thick oracle client on machine where you are running ant
   script and tns-names set up, you can connect inside the sql script
   .. much easier.
2. Create a common task that takes schema as ant parameter ${}-- i
   guess from your build properties -- this will avoid duplication main
   connection code-- and two tasks calling common task passing
   different schema names .. since there are two tasks -- you can use
   specific sql script there.